# Munin: cannot add new custom munin node

Tags: munin

I've written my own simple munin-node implementation, but cannot get it to show on an master (2.0.33-1) in munin-cgi-html.

munin.conf configuration:

```
[uberlamp3]
    address 192.167.0.21
    use_node_name yes
    port 19270
```

I monitor conversation between the master and the node and see see that node is asked for:

1: cap (I return empty caps)

2: list (I return the only plugin - temp)

3: config temp. I return:

```
graph_args --title "Lamp Temperatures"
graph_category Temperatures
temp.label temp
.
```

4: fetch temp. I return:

```
temp.value 47.3
```

5: quit - I drop connection. No errors in munin-update.log

All that is processed normally on munin-update. No errors in munin-update.log. Corresponding rrd file is created and updated with correct values (checked with rrdtool). But munin-cgi-html never show this new node in generated HTML.

munin-update.log:

```
2017/06/23 07:40:01 [INFO] starting work in 9170 for uberlamp3/192.167.0.21:19270.
2017/06/23 07:40:01 [INFO] node uberlamp3 advertised itself as uberlamp.14.by instead.
2017/06/23 07:40:01 [INFO]: Munin-update finished for node uberlamp3;uberlamp3 (0.33 sec)
2017/06/23 07:40:06 [INFO] Reaping Munin::Master::UpdateWorker<uberlamp3;uberlamp3>.  Exit value/signal: 0/0
```

Few more observations:

1) htmlconf.storable - contains references to uberlamp3 node

2) I've tried to add one more native munin-node, which added without issues - and after update shows in html/graphs. uberlamp3 though still not showing.

Any suggestions?

Munin version: 2.0.33-1
Ubuntu Version: tried 16.10 and 17.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, munin is very sensitive to graph configuration returned by node.

After I copy-pasted config response from native nodes (using telnet, then list, then "config uptime" for example), it started working and showed all the old data it captured.

```
graph_title Temperatures
graph_args --base 1000 -l 0
graph_vlabel °C
graph_category system
temp.draw AREA
temp.label temp
.
```

Answer (score 0):

" node uberlamp3 advertised itself as uberlamp.14.by instead."

What happens if you type "hostname" on the client?

Have you checked munin client configuration?

Comment: Tried that. It appears these hostnames mismatches are common thing - happens all the time. The only effect is the name of the node on the web page. I tried to make it match - there were no difference.

Comment: And of course I had no client configuration - as I had my own custom client.